# How can I solve my problem (PDOException: SQLSTATE[25P02])?

Tags: 7, nodes

When I write in my blog I get this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block: SELECT column_name, data_type, column_default FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = :schema AND table_name = :table AND (data_type = 'bytea' OR (numeric_precision IS NOT NULL AND column_default LIKE :default)); Array ( [:schema] => public [:table] => url_alias [:default] => %nextval% ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7239 of /var/www/site/includes/common.inc).

If I write in title some number like 1111 article adding, but if I write some words I get the error. I tried to write an [issue about this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2298219).

Now I've already updated core to 7.33.

I've seen 26 version's core file common.inc and 33 function drupal_write_record and I didn't see any different and file too except some comment strings.

I've seen

> Major changes since 7.26:
>
> Modules which use custom Ajax form page callbacks require updates for Drupal 7.27
>
> This is expected to affect several popular modules such as Field Collection (issue) and Hierarchical Select (issue), although only in cases where the form widgets provided by those modules are exposed to anonymous users.
>
> Modules which provide alternative page cache implementations require updates for Drupal 6.31 and Drupal 7.27
>
> This is expected to affect modules such as Boost and Authcache.
>
> form_set_cache() now validates the passed-in form build ID
>
> This is not expected to affect most sites.

But I didn't see something what I can do. I get the error, how can I solve it?